# How do you rename a farm?

Tags: 2010

SPFarm has a property called DisplayName... which at the moment is the horribly undescriptive value "SharePoint_Config"... which is exactly what farm.Name is.

Is there any way to change the DisplayName to something descriptive, like "Production", or "Staging"?

Is it possible to change this using PowerShell?

Answer (score 3):

I would not make any change to farm level properties like that.  It is not something that the users will ever see and there is a chance that there is configuration data that is tied to that name.

Things I normally do to make it clear which environment you are in include:

- Set a good FQDN like portaldev.acme.com, portalqa.acme.com, portal.acme.com
- Change the Site Name to include the environment for Dev/Test/QA/Staging, etc
- Change the theme for the non-production sites so that it is clear which environment you are in
- Add a feature that can be enabled to add a user control to the masterpage that reads the FQDN and conditionally displays a note for non-production environments

Update:  The SPFarm.DisplayName property supports only a get, not a set and cannot be changed.  The SPFarm.Name property supports both get and set so it could conceivably be changed.

Comment: In addition you can change Title of Central Administration to read something like "Central Administration (PRODUCTION|STAGING)"

Comment: I understand the fear of changing farm properties... but I'm wondering if it's possible.   I can't imagine there could be configuration data tied to DisplayName... Name yes, but DisplayName?

Comment: By the way, this is not something I am wanting to configure so that end-users can tell the difference.  I would like to be able to gather information about a series of farms using PowerShell and analyse that data in aggregate.  Having all of the SPFarm objects use the Name and DisplayName of "Admin_Config" is the issue I'm trying to work around.  Yes, I could look inside of the Farm and see the WebApplications, or the Sites, and figure it out.... but I was hoping to just set the DisplayName on the farm to something useful.